# Is there any way to make cloud-init get the datasource from the hard disk itself?

Tags: datasource, cloud-init, cd-rom

I was implementing the cloud-init feature in our product. i was assigned to implement this without using cd-rom (infact only from the hard disk itself). So is there any way for it?

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You are expected to show what you have tried and what exactly is unclear to you. It would also help if you give one or two simple examples. We will not do your job for you.

Comment: Okay, noted. Its my first question on stack overflow. please excuse my mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. You can use the [NoCloud Datasource](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/datasources/nocloud.html), which will look in `/var/lib/cloud/seed` without special configuration. See the [seed example](https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/blob/master/doc/examples/seed/README) in the cloud-init sources.

Comment: Thank You very much brother. You saved my lot of time.